# Overwrite class generic type

Tags: java, oop, generics

I have this interface:

```java
interface Entity<PK> {
    PK getPk();
    void setPk(PK pk);
}
```

Which I overwrite like this:

```java
class User implements Entity<User.PK> {
    PK pk;

    @Override
    public PK getPk() { return pk; }

    @Override
    public void setPk(PK pk) { this.pk = pk; }

    // Composed primary key
    class PK {
        String id;
        String email;
    }
}
```

But if I would have to extend the User class to extend the generic type `User.PK`, I could not because `the method setPk(UserEntity.PK) of type UserEntity must override or implement a supertype method`.

```java
class UserEntity extends User {
    PK pk;

    @Override
    public PK getPk() { return pk; }

    @Override
    public void setPk(PK pk) { this.pk = pk; }

    class PK extends User.PK implements Serializable {
        String id;
        String email;
    }
}
```

So how can I create an interface for a given generic type but being able to extend the classes that implement it?

Comment: Why do both `User` and `UserEntity` store a PK? Seems like you should first resolve this design flaw before trying to optimize (what exactly?).

Comment: @Smutje because I want to keep `User` as a plain object and `UserEntity` will have jpa related annotations

Comment: So why does a non-entity contains a "PK", a explicit database-specific concept?

Comment: Well, it is a good point, however in the service interface the concept of and "id" exists for generics methods like `get(id)`, `delete(id)`; even if it is database agnostic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice this solution:

1. your `interface Entity<PK>` looks good
2. extract `class PK` definition into separate file with name `UserPk`
3. slightly redefine `User` like this

```
class User<PK> implements Entity<PK> {
    private PK pk;

    @Override
    public PK getPk() { return pk; }

    @Override
    public void setPk(PK pk) { this.pk = pk; }  
}
```

and use it later like `new User<UserPk>()`

4. put into separate class too

```
class UserEntityPk extends UserPk implements Serializable {
        String id;
        String email;
}
```

5. reuse `class User<PK>` in this manner with a new key parameter `new User<UserEntityPk>()`

**The key idea is to separate your parameterized classes from keys' definitions for simplifying architecture.**

BTW just curios what is the difference between your keys' definitions? The both of them have the same `id` and `email` strings. So looks like you don't need `class PK extends User.PK implements Serializable` at all.

Comment: However I would not be able to work directly with the `User` entity. The idea is to keep the it independent of the database layer but being able to overwrite it if necessary for example when using JPA

Comment: What do you mean by "overwrite"?

Comment: @LewBloch I was intending to keep a pure pk class and then extend it to add jpa annotations, however, I end up just using the pk class for jpa because all I needed was to implement Serializable, which seems fine to me.

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer because it answered what I asked